# VBA to attach excel file as attachment and to have worksheet in the body of email

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to run a vba through which I am able to simultaneously attach the workbook to the email, and have selected worksheet embedded into the body of email. Currently I have two sets of code which run these functions independently, is there a method to combine them?

****The vba for attaching into body of email:****

```
Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    'You can also use a sheet name
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").UsedRange

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "Nabil.Hure@dnb.no"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Send                                    'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub



Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

and the vba to send workbook as attachment:

```
    Sub Mail_workbook_Outlook_1()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "Nabil.Hure@dnb.no"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Trades Today" & Date
        .Body = "Please find today's trade report attached."
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Relatively new to vba so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

see below, sorry replying from my phone so couldn't test it, just copying pasting your code together.

```
    Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()

        Dim rng As Range
        Dim OutApp As Object
        Dim OutMail As Object

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = False
            .ScreenUpdating = False
        End With

        Set rng = Nothing
        Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        'You can also use a sheet name
        'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").UsedRange

        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
            .to = "Nabil.Hure@dnb.no"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
            .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
            .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            .Send                                    'or use .Display
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0

        With Application
            .EnableEvents = True
            .ScreenUpdating = True
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
        Set OutApp = Nothing
    End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, I've tried the code however it comes up with Sub or function not defined error in this section of the code: .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)       Do you know how I can correct this?

Comment: Yeah the second part of your code also needs to be there, I will modify the answer to include the function.

Comment: Okay, replaced copy again fully.